# Defining a route with multiple parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I would like to define a route like this

```
https://www.example.com/api/Company/Example/Sequence/0325671?Next=10&Reference=1&Option=none...
```

Where `...` can be 0 to N parameters that can be null or default if not used.

Can I do this?

```
    public IHttpActionResult GetNextRange([FromUri] ParameterDto parameters)
    {

    }

    public class ParameterDto
    {
        public long Next { get; set; }

        public string Reference { get; set; }

        public string Option { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current examples are for .NET Core - using `[FromQuery]` attribute. It case it is Full .NET `[FromUri]` should be used.

In case the parameters are in query string you should use `[FromQuery]` attribute (if it is .NET Core):

```
public IHttpActionResult GetNextRange([FromQuery] ParameterDto parameters)
{
}
```

If you want to map query string parameters to object then you should add this attribute for every needed property:

```
public class ParameterDto
{
    [FromQuery]
    public long Next { get; set; }

    [FromQuery]
    public string Reference { get; set; }

    [FromQuery]
    public string Option { get; set; }
}
```

You can also specify name of parameter:

```
[FromQuery(Name = "some_query_parameter_name")]
```

If you don't know the exact parameters (so why do you need this?) you can get all the parameters from `Request.Query` (.NET Core) or `Request.QueryString` (Full .NET) property:

```
var keys = Request.Query.Keys; // or Request.QueryString.AllKeys;
var parameterValue = Request.Query["parameterName"]; // or Request.QueryString["parameterName"];
```

Comment: I know what will be my parameters but this will increase with time. In fact i create a query and the parameters are options the user can set to custom the result container. Do you want json, do you want this result, do you want a csv, if so which coding, ... So I will by default return a json but I need to be able to return the same result as csv, excel, for some I will probably create multiple entry point in my controller but for other it will be parameters.

Comment: So, you can always extend `ParameterDto` with new parameters or simply get collection from request and pass values where you need without mapping to variables/objects.

Comment: Yes the [FromQuery] is exactly what I need. I just need to check if I can combine this with default initilization but this part I can test on my side now. Thank you.

Comment: But I cannot find the FromQuery Namespace ?

Comment: It is for .NET Core. If you on Full .NET then `[FromUri]` should be used.

Comment: It's not .NET Core.

Comment: See previous comment - use `[FromUri]`

Comment: yep working now. It is just the FromUri is for the class, not I cannor rename each parameter in my class.